# cy.intercept() not working when used with cy.trigger()

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress

I have an input with `type=date` in my form. When its value changes, the app is supposed to call the API `/get_slots` with POST method. I used `cy.type()` and then `cy.trigger('change')` to trigger the API call.

I wanted to use `cy.intercept()` to return mocked data from the fixture file. However, it seems like `cy.intercept()` is never invoked, and the actual API is still being called instead.

Here is the code:

```
// It is supposed to return the slots from fixture file
cy.intercept('POST', '/get_slots', 'fixture:slot-list.json').as('getSlots');

cy.get('input.datepicker')
  .type("2024-01-10")
  .trigger('change')
```

In the ROUTE section, Cypress shows **stubbed = YES**

[image]

I tried to use `cy.wait("@getSlots")` but it shows:

`Timed out retrying after 5000ms: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: getSlots. No request ever occurred.Learn more`

Can anyone help me understand the error here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the screenshot the last column shows the number of hits/matches to the intercept. `-` means no hits.

So either the URL sent from the app to the API does not match `/get_slots` or the POST never happened.

**Does POST occur**

Take a look in the devtools Network tab to see if you POST actually occurs. It may be that `.trigger('change')` is the wrong event, you may need `.trigger('input')` or `cy.get('form').trigger('submit')`.

If you have access to the source code, you can find out what event is being used.

Sometimes you can only get an event to fire using the [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events) plugin, try that as well.

**What routeMatcher is needed**

If the POST is present in devtools, the fault is with the routeMatcher expression, so you need to look at the full URL in devtools and compare it.

The `/get_slots` expression is a glob expression which can be surprisingly finicky. Try wild-carding the previous and following paths `**/get_slots/*`.

Note the `get_slots` should be a complete path segment, i.e all the text between two path separator in the actual URL.

Some other ways routeMatcher can be used

- full URL string (paste in the full URL from devtools)
- regex `/\/get_slots/`